# Can I retrieve a variable from a express function into a script of a pug template?

Tags: express, pug

I have a express function that retrieves one variable(array) from mongoDB

```
app.get('/route',function(req,res,next){
    User.find()
          .exec(function(err,result){
               if(err) throw err
               var outputMessage=result[0].message.split(/\\n/g)
               var myBooks=[]
               for(var i=0;i<outputMessage.length;i++){
                        myBooks.push(outputMessage[i])
                     }
               res.render('index',{books: myBooks}) 
            })

   }
```

And a pug template index.pug:

```
html
   head
     script(type='text/javascript')
        for book in books /*books coming from the express function in res.render('index',{books: myBooks}) */
           data.addRows([book,1]) /*data.addRows are object and method from Google Charts*/
```

Is it posible to use a variable from the express function within a script of the pug template (and within the head)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store `books` array into a javascript variable and then iterate over it using javascript [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
html
    head
        script(type='text/javascript').

            var books = !{JSON.stringify(books)};

            books.forEach( function (book) {
                data.addRow([book,1]);
            });
```

Do not forget dot `.` after `script(type='text/javascript')` that tells pug not interpreting the next code

Comment: Yes, it works, but instead addRows() **addRow()** On the other hand I am glad how it works, but I can't see the logic: it looks like books is retrieved in index.pug as a object, so JSON.stringify(books) to converted again in object {JSON.stringify(books)}.And why ! in front. it seems everything circular.

Comment: I don't know if it's `addRows` or `addRow`, I just copy past your code. In pug you can evaluate a variable inside a text by using #{variable} or !{variable}, the first one escape variable and put it into text, the seconds just put it without escaping. to understand how code works let's consider that your array of books is `['a', 'b']`, the final result that we want to obtain is `var books = ['a', 'b'];`, if you just do `var books = #{books}` you'll get something similar to this: `var books = a, b` that's why we need to transform books to a string using `JSON.stringify`:

Comment: `var books = #{JSON.stringify(books)}`, not that `#{}` will escape the json result and transform double quotes into `& quot;`  that's why we have to use `!{}` instead

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see much better now.

Comment: You are welcome, Consider [marking my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers